# XCODE : Pod Update

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

I am using reachability, SwiftJSON, crashlytics pod files in my projects which is baselined to iOS9. currently I’m XCODE 7 to run my project. now i need to migrate my code to swift 3.0. My question is how to update the pod files. Currently the versions of pod file is 2.3. How can i migrate it to 3.0.

Comment: just type pod update

Comment: Just type `pod update` in terminal.

Answer (score 5):

If you haven't updated cocoapod itself, I recommend you to do a `gem install cocoapods` to get the latest version, working with Xcode 8.x

If your pods are not tagged with any version restriction like `pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 2'` you just need to run `pod update`, otherwise you need to check yourself first which version you need/want for swift 3.

Answer (score 2):

For pod update : type `pod update` in terminal
For migration of your project, open it up in Xcode 8+ and there will an option of automatic conversion. [Check](https://swift.org/migration-guide/) this one out if issues arises.

NOTE: Keep backup of your old project somewhere.